# How to read いい方

Tags: readings

How do you read 方 in

大きいクラスでは、一時間にせいぜい一、二度当たればいい方だ。
In a large class, on a good day, you will be called on at most once or twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be read as 'ほう' 'hou'.

いい here is an adjective means 'good'. It is implicitly comparing this situation with the one when you would never be called, which is bad and also quite possible in this condition (big class). 方 referring to one of the two parties being compared is pronounced ほう.